# Is it possible to export glTF models vertices, UVs and normals with signed short "2 bytes", not float "4 bytes"?

Tags: gltf

I had exported a glTF model from blender, when I put .bin file to hex editor, it seems his vertices, UVs and normals are in "4 bytes" float, or **IEEE 754** floating point, like the example below.

➤ Is it possible to export glTF models with short_signed not float, or "2 bytes" only, not "4 bytes" in the vertices, UVs and normals?

```
Example:

Vertices are in float:
X = 34 80 45 C2 ----short_signed----> xx xx
Y = C1 F9 65 42 ----short_signed----> xx xx
Z = 94 F6 76 41 ----short_signed----> xx xx

UVs are in float:
X = AD 69 0E 3F ----short_signed----> xx xx
Y = 5D FE 63 3F ----short_signed----> xx xx

Normals are in float:
X = 66 96 66 BF ----short_signed----> xx xx
Y = 56 66 DE 3E ----short_signed----> xx xx
Z = 00 00 80 3F ----short_signed----> xx xx
```

➤ If it is impossible, please give me any method to convert this "4 bytes" float hexadecimal to "2 bytes" only, and make it short?      (IEEE 754 floating point --------> signed short)

➤ Or is there another model format with signed short, or "2 bytes" in the vertices, UVs and normals?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61717881/1314762.